# Email System , Replying from PHP vs Software

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, sendmail

I cant get the server to accept my email sent from my end basically i realise it's sending two super different stuff from laravel's mail comparing to hotmail & thunderbird

Basically ,What i normally do is to use hotmail to reply but now i have multiple hotmail i have to manage therefore i was trying to send the email from my web application (laravel) for easier management but the "server" i'm sending to doesnt accept my normal php mail format. I'm definately missing something. Any email experts can advice on this?

Suspect

1. My content is not BASE64
2. In-Reply-To < Not sure about this

**I'm using Hotmail's SMTP**

Normal PHP

```
X-TMN: [Rmqa/GDhCTtKz/QHzf3PJ3OwikNcUBK3]
X-Originating-Email: [My Email]
Message-ID: <BLU436-SMTP1442C473F3D4FDD87CB62F29A410@phx.gbl>
Return-Path: Email.com
Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 17:06:08 +0800
Subject: RE: Subject
From: My Email
To: "Email.com"
 <Email.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 14 Jan 2015 09:06:40.0049 (UTC) FILETIME=[68728A10:01D02FD9]

Email Content in pure Text here
```

Hotmail(Web based)/thunbird style

```
X-TMN: [vnGLLjV7gUOyWwB/t0Ipyc0a9UiAeX10]
X-Originating-Email: [My Email]
Message-ID: <BAY180-W3892FACB7ED35FBDFF773B9A410@phx.gbl>
Return-Path: My Email
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_4c14973f-4b86-4f73-b78c-eac0375a1262_"
From: My Email
To: "Email.com"
    <Email.com>
Subject: RE: Subject
Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 17:03:32 +0800
Importance: Normal
In-Reply-To: <14ae7acae73.1948.26c1bd@ismtpd-063>
References: <14ae7acae73.1948.26c1bd@ismtpd-063>
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_4c14973f-4b86-4f73-b78c-eac0375a1262_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="gb2312"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<base64 here>

--_4c14973f-4b86-4f73-b78c-eac0375a1262_--
```

Comment: I guess you have to set up some SPF and DKIM records - http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21751322-What-are-SPF-and-DKIM-and-do-I-need-to-set-them-up-.

Comment: LOL , my bad, i'm using hotmail's SMTP

Comment: I dont think i own hotmail.com HAHAAHAHA I'm just using hotmail's SMTP

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve it, as suspected, it's Base64. Basically , I had to customize the content Type on my laravel.

```
 $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset="gb2312"');
 $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64');
```